# How do you fix a broken/missing icon (in this case, typing break icon)?

Tags: 10.10, gnome, icons

It used to work fine in another install of Maverick, I don't know why it's broken now.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [someone else with a similar problem](http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg2078313.html). What you need to do is add the indicator applet to the panel (right-click on an empty space in the panel, click Add to Panel, then look for Indicator Applet).